# GIF picture won't animate when displaying a loader/spinner in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

I just want to ask about my problem.
I created a function in jquery that display a loader in my page after searching. But my problem is the image doesn't animate.

Here's my code. I am using Codeigniter and jquery as my framework.

```
 $('#search-btn').on('click',function(){

            var query = $("#keyword").val();

            var image = "<?php echo base_url()."/resources/loading/loading43.gif"; ?>";

            $('#loading').html("<img src='"+image+"' class='loeader' align='center' />");

            var query_url = "<?php echo site_url('item_controller/searchItem'); ?>";

            $.ajax({

                type:'POST',
                url: query_url,
                data:{query: $("#keyword").val()},
                dataType:'json',
                async: false,
                success:function(d){

                    $('#loading').html("").hide();

                    //$('.display').dataTable().fnDestroy( true );

                    $("#example tbody").html("");

                    for(i in d){

                        $("#example tbody").append("<tr><td style='text-align: center; color:' data-code='TRUE'>" + d[i]['item_code'] + "</td><td style='text-align: left' data-name='TRUE'>" + d[i]['item_name'] + "</td><td><div style='text-align: center'><input type='button' value='ADD' class='k-button' id='" + d[i]['item_code'] + "' data-item=TRUE /></div></td></tr>");

                    }

                    //$("#search_result").show('blind');

                    $("[data-item]").on('click',function(){

                        var code = $(this).parents('tr').find('[data-code]').html();
                        var name = $(this).parents('tr').find('[data-name]').html();
                        // console.log(code,name);
                        $("#grid1 tbody").append("<tr><td style='text-align: center; width: 20%'><input type='text' name='code[]' value=" + code + " readonly style='width:50px; background-color: transparent; border-style: none' id=code" + counter_code++ +" /></td><td style='text-align: center; width: 40%'><input type='text' style='width: 90%; background-color: transparent; border-style: none' name='item_name[]' value='" + name + "' id=item"+ counter_item++ +" readonly /></td><td style='text-align: center'><input type='text' name='qty[]' id=qty"+ counter_qty++ +" style='text-align: center; width: 50px;' /></td><td style='text-align: center'><div align='center'><select style='width:100px; display: block' name='unit[]' id=unit"+ counter_unit++ +" ><option value=''>----</option><option value='pc/pcs'>PC/PCS</option><option value='BOX/BOXES'>BOX/BOXES</option></select></div></td><td style='text-align: center'><input type='text' name='price[]' id=price"+ counter_price++ +" style='text-align: right; width: 100px;' onblur='' /></td><td style='text-align: center'><input type='text' name='total[]' id=total"+ counter_total++ +" style='font-family: courier; text-align: right; background-color: lightgray; color: red; width: 100px;' readonly='readonly' value='' /></td></tr>");

                        ComputeTotal();

                    });

                    $('.display').dataTable({
                        "bPaginate": true,
                        "bLengthChange": true,
                        "bFilter": true,
                        "bSort": true,
                        "bInfo": true,
                        "bAutoWidth": false,
                        "bDestroy": true,
                        "bJQueryUI": false,
                        "bRetrieve": true,
                        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                        "iDisplayLength": 25,
                        "destroy": true
                    });

                    //$('.display').dataTable().fnDestroy(true);

                    //$('.display').children().remove()

                },

            });    

....




<div id="loading"></div>

<div id="search_result" class="k-content">
     <div class="k-header" id="item-view-list" align="center">

        <table border="0" style="width: 80%; align: left" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="10" align="left">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3">
                    <h5>SEARCH ITEM</h5>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 3%">
                    <label>Enter Item Code</label>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 40%">
                    <input type="text" name="keyword" id="keyword" style="width: 80%" /> <input type="button" value="SEARCH" id="search-btn" class="k-button" style="font-size: 12px" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <hr />

        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="example" style="font-size:small; width: 100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>CODE</th>
                    <th>NAME/DESCRIPTION</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

            </tbody>
        </table>
        <br />

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry sir, but i just paste my code for reference. My only problem is the image that i included which is a GIF image won't animate when I tried to display it in my form.

Comment: maybe it's because your ajax `async: false` it's causing all the page freeze until it's finish the statement(In this case the ajax process).

Comment: so what should i do to animate my image?

Comment: Feedback here? Did an answer below help you resolve?

Answer (score 1):

This happens because the image loading is asynchronous and before it finishes to load you start the ajax loading (which is also async). Now they are competing about getting first in the event queue.

You can try do give the image a chance to load first - the best would be to invoke the ajax call using the image's `onload` callback.

You can also try to delay the ajax call doing this, just wrap your $.ajax like this:

```
setTimeout(function() {$.ajax({

        type:'POST',
        url: query_url,
        data:{query: $("#keyword").val()},
        dataType:'json',
        async: false,
        success:function(d){ ...

...}}, 250); // delays 250 milliseconds
```

Depending on how much time the image loading takes you might want to increase or decrease the timeout.

This is why a `onload` event should be used instead:

```
$('#loading').html("<img src='"+image+"' class='loeader' 
                    align='center' onload='start()' />");

function start() {
    $.ajax({

        type:'POST',
        url: query_url,
        data:{query: $("#keyword").val()},
        dataType:'json',
        async: false,
        success:function(d){ ...

    ...})
};
```